# Linking an index inside an array of objects to a specific HTML div relatively

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, swiper.js

I have a array of objects which contain images (below). I need to append each image to a specific `<div>` which is inside the container 'slider-container'.

**JSON:**

```
{
"slideData": [{
    "brand": "http://placehold.it/200x50?text=1" // index 0
}, {
    "brand": "http://placehold.it/200x50?text=2" // index 1
}, {
    "brand": "http://placehold.it/200x50?text=3" // index 2
}]
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="slider-container">

<div class="swiper-slide">
<!-- image from index 0 should append here (slideData.[0].brand) -->
</div>

<div class="swiper-slide">
<!-- image from index 1 should append here (slideData.[1].brand) -->
</div>

<div class="swiper-slide">
<!-- image from index 2 should append here (slideData.[2].brand) -->
</div>

</div>
```

The comments in the code above should explain what i mean, also there is code below with the swiper.js slider being used. When you run the code, it looks like the slider is initialising in a weird manner.

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  loop: true,
  init: false,
  // Navigation arrows
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
});

swiper.on('init', function() {
  var imgObj = {
    "slideData": [{
      "brand": "http://placehold.it/200x50?text=1" // index 0
    }, {
      "brand": "http://placehold.it/200x50?text=2" // index 1
    }, {
      "brand": "http://placehold.it/200x50?text=3" // index 2
    }]
  }

  $('.sy-slide .brand').each(function (idx, div) {
    if (idx > 0) idx--;
    else if (idx == 0) idx++;
    if (idx >= imgObj.slideData.length) idx = 0;
    $(div).append('<img src=' + imgObj.slideData[idx].brand + '></img>');
  });
  
});

swiper.init();
```

```css
.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 53px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.3.3/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.3.3/css/swiper.min.css">

<div class="swiper-container">

  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <!-- Slides -->
    <div class="swiper-slide sy-slide">Slide 1
      <div class="brand"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide sy-slide">Slide 2
      <div class="brand"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide sy-slide">Slide 3
      <div class="brand"></div>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>

  <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `querySelectorAll()` to get all the `div`. Then iterate over all the elements to add images from proper index of the object's array:

```js
var imgObj = {
  "slideData": [{
      "brand": "http://placehold.it/200x50?text=1" // index 0
  }, {
      "brand": "http://placehold.it/200x50?text=2" // index 1
  }, {
      "brand": "http://placehold.it/200x50?text=3" // index 2
  }]
}

document.querySelectorAll('.swiper-slide').forEach(function(div, idx){
  div.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<img src='+imgObj.slideData[idx].brand+'></img>');
  //OR
  //div.innerHTML += '<img src='+imgObj.slideData[idx].brand+'></img>'
});
```

```html
<div class="swiper-slide">
</div>

<div class="swiper-slide">
</div>

<div class="swiper-slide">
</div>
```

***As you asked for a*** jQuery solution:

```js
var imgObj = {
  "slideData": [{
      "brand": "http://placehold.it/200x50?text=1" // index 0
  }, {
      "brand": "http://placehold.it/200x50?text=2" // index 1
  }, {
      "brand": "http://placehold.it/200x50?text=3" // index 2
  }]
}

$('.swiper-slide').each(function(idx, div){
  $(div).append('<img src='+imgObj.slideData[idx].brand+'></img>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="swiper-slide">
</div>

<div class="swiper-slide">
</div>

<div class="swiper-slide">
</div>
```

I know this might not be the proper way to handle the issue but you can consider this as a workaround:

```
$('.swiper-slide .brand').each(function(idx, div) {
  var i = $(div).parent().attr("data-swiper-slide-index");
  $(div).append('<img src=' + imgObj.slideData[i].brand + '></img>');
});
```

Full Working Example:

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  loop: true,
  init: false,
  // Navigation arrows
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
});

swiper.on('init', function() {
  var imgObj = {
    "slideData": [{
      "brand": "http://placehold.it/200x50?text=1" // index 0
    }, {
      "brand": "http://placehold.it/200x50?text=2" // index 1
    }, {
      "brand": "http://placehold.it/200x50?text=3" // index 2
    }]
  }

  $('.sy-slide .brand').each(function (idx, div) {
    let i = $(div).parent().attr("data-swiper-slide-index");
  $(div).append('<img src=' + imgObj.slideData[i].brand + '></img>');
  });
  
});

swiper.init();
```

```css
.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 53px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.3.3/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.3.3/css/swiper.min.css">

<div class="swiper-container">

  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <!-- Slides -->
    <div class="swiper-slide sy-slide">Slide 1
      <div class="brand"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide sy-slide">Slide 2
      <div class="brand"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide sy-slide">Slide 3
      <div class="brand"></div>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>

  <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, how would I do the same thing using jquery? I am using $.getJSON to load the data since it is externally hosted.

Comment: @zxynz, I have added the solution with jQuery as well.........please check.

Comment: thanks it works without the slider but when its inside the slide it is breaking. Please take a look at the updated question i put an runnable piece of code there

Comment: @zxynz, the issue is related to Swiper....as I am not a guy expert on that you should ask a new question with that tag.........

Comment: @zxynz, I have updated the answer with a workaround....you can try that...though swiper should have some built in property to handle the issue automatically......thanks

Comment: it works but when you press the back button - you will see the order breaks? Please have a look by going to the code example and pressing the back button? Thanks @Mamun

Comment: Thanks! It works! I just tweaked the variable you used to grab the parent 'data-swiper-slide-index': $('.slide-container .brand').parents().eq(2)